# How to insert a line break within the for loop of a print statement using python

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using the following code to print the list of friends in twitter

> > users = api.friends()
> >     print([u.name for u in users])

I get the following output

> > ['The New York Times', 'BBC Breaking News', 'Oprah Winfrey']

But I want something like this

> > ['The New York Times',
> >      'BBC Breaking News',
> >      'Oprah Winfrey' 
> >     ]

Comment: I would like to have to square brackets. That's where I am finding it difficult and the print statement works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below works

`import pprint
 users = api.friends()
 pprint.pprint([u.name for u in users], width=1)`

Comment: Thank you its working... But should remove the width parameter or its splitting each word like The,newyork,times...

Comment: from https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html, when width is too low it mades best effort, since the width is low it can not break items in between.

Answer (score 2):

Just break the code, Write loop and then print each name

```
for u in users:
       print u.name
       print ""
```

Comment: You can also just do `print(u.name)` in Python 3, because a newline is automatically added unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to keep the list brackets, quotes, and commas? If you just want to print the items one per line, you could do something like:

```
print(*[u.name for u in users], sep='\n')
```

Or you could loop and print each item individually:

```
for u in users:
    print(u.name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
print('\n'.join([u.name for u in users]))
```

Comment: I want the include the square brackets as well. That is the place I got stuck